# Join first letter in each element of map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, join

I'm having a strange issue.

```
var names = [
  'double',
  'illy',
  'grand',
  'stuck'
];
var user = names.map(function (n) {
  n[0]
}).join('');
```

alert(user);
This should print out "digs" but it doesn't 
it just prints out blank.

I'm not sure what the problem is here.

Comment: u need to return a value in map. return n[0];

Answer (score 2):

You need to return a value in the map function. Right now you are returning `undefined`. Try this,

```
var user = names.map(function (n) {
  return n[0];
}).join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `n[0]` to `return n[0]` to actually return the value.

Have a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qc1jy4b7/).

Hope that helps! :)